# Independence of variables implies no functional representation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question's pretty simple, I just thought the title phrases it pretty well..

Anyway, the Doob-Dynkin lemma says that $X$ is $\sigma (Y)$-measurable iff there's a measurable $f$ such that $X=f(Y)$ (this is what I refer to as a functional representation, henceforth "f.r"). Intuitively, If two random variables are independent I don't except them to have a f.r of each other. Then again my intuition sucks.. So the question is (*edit: for not a.s constant $X,Y$*)$$\sigma(X)\perp\sigma(Y)\overset{?}{\implies}\text{no f.r}$$I don't know how to connect measurability and independence..

*Update: found and posted solution from stats.stack*

Comment: you could take trivial (constant) variables as a counterexample I suppose

Comment: what about nontrivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution (I didn't think of it myself) so I'm posting it. I'm not sure what the protocol is for answering your own question.

Under the assumption $X,Y$ are not a.s constant, the first answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/are-the-random-variables-x-and-fx-dependent) proves the contrapositive.